# On the definition of quotient group

Tags: group-theory

Wikipedia says the following:

> This defines an operation on G/N, because we have the following equalities of subsets of G:
>
> $(aN)(bN) = a(Nb)N = a(bN)N = (ab)NN = (ab)N.$

But I don't see how these manipulations are being made. I can believe $aNb = abN$ but here we have two $N$s. How is $NN$ a subset of $G$?

Comment: $NN=\{xy:x,y\in N\}$

Comment: How did you define the product of cosets if you didn't define $(eN)(eN)$ where $e$ is the identity? And $eN=N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two subsets $A, B \subseteq G$, we define $AB = \{ab : a \in A,\ b \in B\}$ to be the set consisting of all products of things in $A$ with things in $B$ (and note that, no matter what, it's certainly a subset of $G$).

Use this definition to verify that $NN = \{n_1n_2 : n_1, n_2 \in N\} = N$, since $N$ is a subgroup hence closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

$NN = N$ because $N$ is subgroup and $n_1 n_2 \in N \forall n_1, n_2 \in N$.

Comment: And also because $1\in N$.

Answer (score 0):

becausethe quotient is defines then $N$ is subnormal in $G$ ( it's a subgroup)

we will proove the 2 inclusions

let be $x,y\in N$ then $xy \in N$ (N a subgroup) so $NN \subset N$

let be $x\in N$ then $x=x.1$ so $N \subset NN$

finally $N=NN$